# Как уменьшить размер тензора в keras?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, tensorflow, keras

есть тензор из 1628670 элементов, задача через reshape сделать его размеров (70, 20, 1), то есть имеющий 140 элементов
Только 1628670 не кратен 140, ближайшее кратное-1628620
Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить размер тензора на несколько единиц?

Comment: Ваш вопрос из разряда "Как изменить массив размером 20 на массив размером 15" ну очевидно удалить 5 элементов, В `keras` как и в остальных фреймворках под капотом тензоры хранятся в виде `1d` массивов, просто у этих массивов есть определенные метаданные, с помощью которых можно выставить любую форму, транспонировать и совершать другие действия без изменения исходного массива, в ответ на ваш вопрос как изменить форму на меньшую ну очевидно удалить из массива такое кол-во элементов которое нужно, что бы он подошел под нужную форму

Comment: Ну вот у меня есть модель, есть keras.layers.Conv2d, затем нужно взять срез, а после этого идет keras.layers.reshape

Comment: Очевидно, что мне нужен какой-то метод keras, дабы извлечь срез в середине модели, но как?

Comment: Возможно вам нужно выполнить, что то вроде `maxpool`-а. Подберите такой размер ядра и `stride`(размер шага), который после свертки даст вам нужный размер тензора

Comment: Может стоит использовать Cropping2d?

Comment: Но правда я не знаю, как удалить ровно 50 элементов, возможно нужен для начала flatten